# measure of the intersection of compact sets

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$ be a nonnegative measurable function on $[0,1]$ such that $\int_0^1 f(x) dx = 1$. Define a measure $\mu$ on $[0,1]$ by
\begin{align*}
\mu(A) = \int_A f(x) dx
\end{align*} for $A \in \mathcal{B}([0,1])$. Let $K$ be the intersection of all compact subsets $E$ of $[0,1]$ such that $\mu(E)=1$. What is $\mu(K)$?

My intuition tells me that $\mu(K) = 1$. I have been trying to look at the $K^c$ which is an infinite union of open sets with $\mu$-measure 0. If I can express $K^c$ as a countable union of $\mu$-measure 0 sets, but I am not sure how to? I haven't used the compactness hypothesis at all either...

Comment: First of all, you *have* used compactness, in that $[0,1]$ is bounded, so compactness is equivalent to closedness. So you've used the compactness to say that $K^c$ is open. Second, a useful property of $\mathbb{R}$ is that any open set can be written as a countable disjoint union of intervals. (This essentially follows from the density of the rationals.) Perhaps you can use this.

Comment: Hint: show that the union of all (relatively) open subsets of $[0,1]$ of measure zero is also the union of all (relatively) open intervals with rational endpoints of measure zero.

Comment: If $x\in I=(c,d)$ with $\mu(I)=0$, then you can build a maximal such interval: let $a=\inf\{ c': \mu((c',d))=0\}$. Then also $\mu((a,d))=0$ (consider a sequence decreasing to $a$), and you can define $b$ similarly. Two such maximal intervals are disjoint or identical, so you can label them by a rational in the interior and you have obtained a maximal open set with $\mu(U)=0$.

Comment: This works for all topological spaces with a countable basis: the union of any family of open subsets equals the union of a countable subfamily.

Comment: @Ian Does this mean that this is true for the intersect of all closed subsets $E$ such that $\mu(E)=1$ also?

Comment: @user125084 Sure, a subset of $[0,1]$ is compact if and only if it is closed.